# How to open Running Apps settings page?

Tags: android, android-intent

Basically, I want to open the Runnings Apps page (the one in the Application Manager in the settings) and eventually, the page of an active app (knowing its package name for example).

Is that even possible? I looked at the documentation and only found a way to open the *All Applications* (using [ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_APPLICATIONS_SETTINGS)) settings page.

Thanks you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not believe that there is a documented and supported `Intent` action for "Running Apps".

For the Settings page of an individual app, [use `ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
  intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
  startActivity(intent);
```